CKQuery returning nothing when record exists
I am implementing login capabilities to an app using a cloudkit database. The record exists and I know its the right cloudDB because the sign up function works properly so if someone could provide some guidance it would be much appreciated.
private func loginUser() async throws {
        do {
            let userRecords = try await getUserRecord()
            
            // Check if we got any results
            guard let retrievedUser = userRecords.first else {
                // Handle the case where no user was found
                throw LoginError.userNotFound
            }
            
            let user = try await User(ckrecord: retrievedUser)
            model.user = user
        } catch {
            // Handle any other errors (e.g., network issues, CK errors)
            throw error
        }
    }

    private func getUserRecord() async throws -> [CKRecord] {
        let cloudDB = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
        
        // Ensure the email comparison is case-insensitive
        let pred = NSPredicate(format: "email == %@ AND password == %@", email, password)
        
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "UserInfo", predicate: pred)
        
        // Query the public record
        let (userResults, _) = try await cloudDB.records(matching: query)
        
        // Return the public CKRecord of the user
        return userResults.compactMap { _, result in
            guard let record = try? result.get() else { return nil }
            return record
        }
    }

    // Define a custom error for login failure
    enum LoginError: Error {
        case userNotFound
    }

here is the info about a UserInfo Record:

